# Why does quantum random walk show ballistic transport?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, interference

For the topic of quantum random walk, a simple example is considering a 1D lattice fermionic model, expressed as

$H = \sum_{i} c_i^\dagger c_{i+1} + h.c.$

Assuming there is one fermion located at the $m$-th lattice point at $t=0$, i.e. the wave function can be expressed as $|\varphi\rangle = |m\rangle$, one find that the growth of the standard deviation of the particle number distribution is linear, so called "ballistic transport".
I am taught in the lessons that this phenomena is due to the quantum interference.
However, how can I understand how quantum interference lead to the ballistic behavior in constrast to the diffusive behavior of classical random walk?

Comment: It is easy to calculate the expression of the time evolution of particle number, but I still cannot understand the physical origin of the ballistic transport.

Answer (score 1):

For a more physical understanding than simple "interference," it helps to know that, while the mean position of the particle is always $\left\langle X(t) \right\rangle = X(0) = m$, the mean and typical displacements are quite different. Basically, the probability distribution function of the particle (versus site $n$) is bimodal, peaked at roughly $m \pm v t$, for some velocity $v = \sqrt{2}$ (I think, see below).

The classical intuition for a random walk doesn't really apply here because it's not some particle just going back and forth at random making stochastic choices. Rather, there are a bunch of "momentum modes" that solve this free model, which are plane waves that propagate ballistically and in different directions. This is related to the model's integrability, and results in a distribution peaked about two peaks (fronts) propagating outward from the initial position.

More generally, you can think of ballistic transport as resulting whenever the current conjugate to a conserved quantity (in the hydrodynamic sense) is itself conserved. Suppose that $\rho$ is a conserved density (e.g. charge or particle number), in which case the continuity equation is $\partial_t \rho + \partial_x J = 0$ (in 1d). If the conjugate current $J$ itself obeys a continuity equation $\partial_t J + \partial_x T = 0$, then you'll see ballistic motion of the quantity $\rho$. Basically, you'll have $\partial_t \rho + v \partial_x \rho = ...$.

A very common example of this is Maxwell's equations in vacuum! The $E$ and $B$ fields are *both* conserved in the absence of matter, and by Ampère's and Faraday's law, they are each other's current (i.e., if $\rho_i = B_i$ is a conserved charge then $J_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk} E_k$ is the conjugate current, where $E$ is itself conserved). The resulting wave equation has ballistic propagation!

Having a conserved current is also generic to **integrable** quantum models (in 1d). Examples of integrable systems include all free fermion models (like the one you've written) and a number of interacting 1d models with translation invariance. Ballistic motion of quasiparticles (and sometimes other things like energy or charge or spin) is a standard feature of these models, because the currents conjugate to the conserved charges are themselves conserved charges. This is true even for interacting integrable models.

For free models, it's even simpler. The occupation of each momentum mode $k$ is *independently conserved*, as are all functions of the form $k^n c^\dagger_k c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k$. The case $n=1$ basically says that current is conserved.

We can also just show this directly for the model you provided! Basically, the local density operator for site $n$ is $\rho_n = c^\dagger_n c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_n$, and the corresponding current (most easily obtained by introducing a gauge field) for site $n$ is just $J_n = i \left( c^\dagger_n c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_{n+1} - c^\dagger_{n+1} c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_n \right)$. It is easy to check that this quantity commutes with the Hamiltonian you wrote down, and is thus itself conserved.

**Below, I've derived the ballistic growth of the standard deviation, and I've commented more on the current stuff at the end**.

Since we only have one fermion, it's just a particle hopping on a lattice. Let's suppose the 1d lattice is infinite and work in Fourier space, where have that
$$ H = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k}{\pi} \cos (k)  \left| k \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle k \right| ~~~\text{and}~~~\left| \psi (0) \right\rangle = \left| m \right\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} \, e^{i k m} \, \left| k \right\rangle ,$$
and so we have the time-evolved state
$$ \left| \psi (t) \right\rangle = e^{- i H t} \left| \psi (0) \right\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} \, e^{i (k m - 2 t \cos (k)) } \, \left| k \right\rangle \, $$
which we can rewrite in the position basis as
$$ \left| \psi (t) \right\rangle = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k}{2\pi} \, e^{i (k (m-n) - 2 t \cos (k) )} \, \left| n \right\rangle \, ,$$
and so the expectation value of the position operator $X = \sum_n n \, \left| n \middle\rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \middle\langle n \right|$ is given by
$$ \left\langle X (t) \right\rangle = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} n \iint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k \text{d}q}{(2\pi)^2} e^{i ((k-q) (m-n) + 2 t \cos (q) - 2 t \cos (k) )},$$
which we can rewrite as
$$ \left\langle X (t) \right\rangle =  \iint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k \text{d}q}{(2\pi)^2} \, e^{i(k-q)m} e^{2 it (\cos (q) - \cos (k))} \, \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (i \partial_k ) e^{i (q-k)n} ,$$
which becomes
$$ \left\langle X (t) \right\rangle =  -\iint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k \text{d}q}{2 \pi i} \, e^{i(k-q)m} e^{2 it (\cos (q) - \cos (k))} \left[  \partial_k  \delta (k - q) \right],$$
and from our knowledge of the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives), this is then
$$  \left\langle X (t) \right\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d} q}{2\pi i} \left. \left( i m + 2 i t \sin (k) \right) e^{i(k-q)m} e^{2 it (\cos (q) - \cos (k))} \right|_{k=q}$$
which simplifies to
$$ \left\langle X (t) \right\rangle = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d} q}{2\pi} \left( m + 2 t \sin (q) \right) = m $$
and then I guess if you wanted the variance, you'd need to evaluate
$$ \left\langle X^2 (t) \right\rangle =  \iint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k \text{d}q}{(2\pi)^2} \, e^{i(k-q)m} e^{2 it (\cos (q) - \cos (k))} \, \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} (i \partial_k )^2 e^{i (q-k)n} ,$$
which we can rewrite as
$$ \left\langle X^2 (t) \right\rangle =  \iint_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}k \text{d}q}{(2\pi)^2} \, e^{i(k-q)m} e^{2 it (\cos (q) - \cos (k))} \, \left[ -2 \pi \, \delta^{(2)} (k - q) \right],$$
and we can use a similar trick as above to write this as
$$ \left\langle X^2 (t) \right\rangle = - \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}q}{2\pi} \, \left. \partial^2_k e^{i(k-q)m} e^{2 it (\cos (q) - \cos (k))} \right|_{k=q} ,$$
which is given by
$$ \left\langle X^2 (t) \right\rangle = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{\text{d}q}{2\pi} \, \left( m^2 + 2 m t \sin (q) + 4 t^2 \sin^2 (q) - 2 i t \cos (q) \right) = m^2 + 2 t^2 ,$$
so that the variance is
$$ \sigma^2 =  \left\langle X^2 (t) \right\rangle - \left\langle X (t) \right\rangle^2 = 2 t^2 , $$
as you / your instructor claimed. I don't know if you were looking for something more "physical" than the derivation. But I think the idea is basically that there are processes that contribute in which the particle hops only to the right and only to the left. At the level of the expectation value, these probability amplitudes cancel out so you get expectation value $m$. But at the level of a variance, these "paths" contribute.

This $t^2$ term comes from the "coherences" in the evolution that do not exist at the level of a classical Markov process, where everything is real valued and there are no probability amplitudes. The classical random walk acts directly on the probabilities to be at each position $n$, rather than quantum probability *amplitudes*. These probabilities get smeared out in time and form a normal distribution centered at $m$.

Anyway, returning to the idea of the current $J$, we note that the Hamiltonian can be written straightforwardly as
$$ H = \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \text{d} k \, \varepsilon (k) \, c^\dagger_k c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k ~~~\text{where}~~~\varepsilon (k) = 2 t \cos (k )\, ,$$
and we note that the *density* of fermions with momentum $k$ is given by $c^\dagger_k c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k$.

The current operator I wrote above is given by
$$ J = i \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \left( c^\dagger_n c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_{n+1} - c^\dagger_{n+1} c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_n \right) = 2 \int_0^{2 \pi} \text{d}k \, \sin (k) c^\dagger_k c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k \, ,$$
or maybe the integral expression has the wrong sign. Anyway, the *current density* at momentum $k$ is given by
$$ \mathcal{J}(k) = \sin (k) c^\dagger_k c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k,$$
which commutes with the Hamiltonian! In fact, *all quantities* of the form $k^n c^\dagger_k c^{\vphantom{\dagger}}_k$ commute with the Hamiltonian! These are the "extensive set of conserved quantities" associated with all integrable systems. Integrability --- and particularly, the fact that the current operator is conserved --- guarantees ballistic growth.

Hopefully that helped.